# Unable to add iOS platform to Cordova project with cordova-plugin-firebasex

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links, cordova-plugin-firebasex

The firebasex Cordova plugin is driving me up the walls! My project has worked fine for months until I updated the cordova-plugin-firebasex from 11.0.3-cli to 14.1.0. This is the error I am getting now after running Cordova platform add ios:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebasex': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 31
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/mmhayes/Documents/MyQCWeb/MyQC_v6_7/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:136:25)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
```

My environment:

```
Cordova -v
11.0.0

Cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  ios 6.2.0
Available platforms: 
  android ^10.1.1
  browser ^6.0.0
  electron ^3.0.0
  osx ^6.0.0

Cordova plugin ls
cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics 6.1.0 "FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks 6.1.3 "FirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin"
cordova-plugin-firebasex 14.1.0 "Google Firebase Plugin"
```

I believe the issue has something to do with the pod versions but I'm not sure. There isn't much on the web about the "exit code 31" error. What little there was, I tried their suggested solutions with no luck. This included running

```
Cordova clean
Cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebasex
Cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
pod repo update
sudo gem install cocoa pods
```

I know this goes without saying, but any help is much appreciated! I can provide more info about my environment if it would be helpful.

### Edit 10/25 4:22PM

My project's Podfile:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'My Quickcharge' do
    project 'My Quickcharge.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 8.8.0'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 8.8.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '9.1.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth', '9.1.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '9.1.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance', '9.1.0'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '9.1.0'
    pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging', '9.1.0'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :tag => '9.1.0', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '9.1.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Functions', '9.1.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Installations', '9.1.0'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn', '6.2.1'
    pod 'GoogleTagManager', '7.4.1'
end
```

Also, when I try to run `pod install --repo-update` I get this error:

```
pod install --repo-update
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.11.3 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods`

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.3

Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/DynamicLinks":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/DynamicLinks (= 6.33.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/DynamicLinks (= 6.33.0)`.

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

Comment: What's your pod version? Did you init pod? updated dependencies?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my question. My pod version is 1.11.2. Yes my project has been working for a while now, but after updating the Cordova-plugin-firebase from 11.0.3-cli to 14.1.0, it broke and won't build on iOS. I will include my Podfile above in my question

Comment: I added my Podfile above as well as the error I get when I try to run "pod install --repo-update"

Comment: I still don't see where you run sudo gem install cocoapods-dependencies and then pod dependencies

Comment: The error I was referring too was when I ran pod install --repo-update. When I ran sudo gem install cocoapods-dependencies and then pod dependencies, it wouldn't even recognize the command. Seemed to be some issue with installing the cocoapods-dependencies package. I appreciate your time Eric, and will take your advice and open an issue in the repo when I have a chance.

Comment: did you run that command from the platform/ios directory ?

Comment: Yessir, I did. I've concluded that the underlying issue behind the "exit code 31" error that is thrown when I try to build, is that I updated the firebasex plugin, without updating the other firebase plugins (analytics and dynamiclinks). Because of this, they require different versions of the firebase core sdk. So now I believe the solution is to find the correct versions of each plugin that use the same core sdk. Just haven't been able to do that yet. I will post an update if/when I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this same issue, we finally found a solution:

As noted above, the problem appeared to be that the Firebase SDK pod versions, which our two Firebase plugins relied on (`cordova-plugin-firebasex` & `cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks`), were out of sync after updating the firebasex plugin.

After much trial and error, we finally aligned the pod versions by installing the right plugin versions and passing the correct `IOS_FIREBASE_SDK_VERSION` variables during installation.

We had success by installing `cordova-plugin-firebasex@16.0.0` and `cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks@7.0.2`. Both were passed the same `IOS_FIREBASE_SDK_VERSION="10.2.0"` variable. Here are the complete plugin installation commands (minus app-specific variables like `APP_DOMAIN_PATH`, etc):

```
cordova plugin install cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks --variable IOS_FIREBASE_SDK_VERSION="10.2.0"
cordova plugin install cordova-plugin-firebasex --variable IOS_FIREBASE_SDK_VERSION="10.2.0"
```

After installing the plugins, you can verify the pod versions are all aligned by opening `plugins/cordova-plugin-firebasex/plugin.xml` and look for something like this:

```
<pods use-frameworks="true">
    <pod name="Firebase/Core" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="Firebase/Auth" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="Firebase/Messaging" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="Firebase/Performance" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="Firebase/RemoteConfig" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="Firebase/InAppMessaging" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="Firebase/Firestore" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="Firebase/Crashlytics" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="Firebase/Functions" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="Firebase/Installations" spec="10.2.0"/>
    <pod name="GoogleSignIn" spec="6.2.4"/>
    <pod name="GoogleTagManager" spec="7.4.2"/>
</pods>
```

We found that after all of the Firebase SDK pod versions were aligned, the builds ran without issue.

Answer (score -1):

It is literally in the documentation of the plugin.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-dependencies
cd platforms/ios/
pod dependencies
```

If you receive a build error such as this:
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `Firebase/Analytics (~> 6.1.0), Firebase/Analytics (= 6.1.0, ~> 6.1.0)`.

Make sure your local Cocoapods repo is up-to-date by running pod repo update then run pod install in `/your_project/platforms/ios/`.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#cocoapods

Comment: Tried that, it changed nothing and outputted the same error I posted in the edit to my new post. Thanks anyways

Comment: Then open an issue to the repo